# Javascript - use the return number of a function to calculate the total

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I have separated my form in different functions and although each one works, I can't find a way to use the value returned in the total function.

```js
function adult() {
  let a = document.getElementById("adulte").value;
  let t = a * 100
  document.getElementById("asub").innerHTML = t
  //document.getElementById("sub-a").value = t;
  console.log(t);
  document.getElementById("tprice").innerHTML = a;
  return t;
}

function total() {
  let a = adult();
  document.getElementById("tprice").innerHTML = a;
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<input id="adulte" name="adulte" style="width: 40px" onchange="adult();" />
<span id="aprice"> 100</span>$/nuit
<p> Hébergements pour les adultes = <span id="asub">100</span>$</p>

<button id="total" name="total" onclick="total();">calculate</button>
<span id="tprice"> 50</span>$
```

Comment: It is working as expected. What else are you expecting?

Comment: I think you are expecting to calculate on Keypress Enter, where it does not trigger total()

Comment: @HR01M8055, I guess because the calculate gives 2 instead of 200, it has me mixed up. I also have other small functions that would use return to change default values (ie: if there are children, then the default choice for hotel would include a kitchenette).

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code should work, but I recommend to use `form` tag..

You don't want trigger `adult()` every time on input change, which I feel is unnecessary and redundant. still there is a lot of room for code optimization, but I don't want to spoil your method of doing things.

> Also in html5, [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event triggered on two conditions :
>
> 1.on Enter Key Press
> 2.on loosing focus (on blur)

```
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function adult(input) {
      let a = input;
      document.getElementById('asub').innerHTML = a * 100;
      document.getElementById('tprice').innerHTML = a;
      return t;
  }

  function total(event) {
    let a = adult(event.target.value);
    document.getElementById('tprice').innerHTML = a;
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="adulte" name="adulte" style="width: 40px" onchange="total(event)" min=0 />
  <span id="aprice"> 100</span>$/unit
  <p>Hébergements pour les adultes = <span id="asub">100</span>$</p>

  <button id="total" name="total" onclick="total();">calculate</button>
  <span id="tprice"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Added Stackblitz code: [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fpyapk?file=index.html)

Comment: so if I have other small functions (one for number of childre, hotel type, etc), do I then just keep adding the variables in the total function and keep it as onchange="total(event)" in each input?